# Add Multiple Google account in Android App

Tags: android, google-account, googlesigninaccount

Currently, i am able to add single account using Google Plus Api provided by Google in Android App.

Q: I want to support multiple google Account, get back multiple access token for all the accounts ? App need is that it has to be implemented using Google Api provided by Android. Implementing using Web-view is not recommended.

Solution Tried: disconnecting current and getting the new Account, but unfortunately it revoke the access of old Account.

Please guide me a way, thanks in advance..

Comment: I have the same issue so can you please suggest me the solution.

Comment: @TejaDroid - I have took the approach of custom Pop-up which will make a Google gettoken() for multiple Account. And store that Accounts locally, Whenever i need to revoke any account just delete the key and make a fresh Call ot getToken again. SO, instead of Google popup of Account i made my own Popup for All connected accounts .. I hope this will help